Mathlib4 Calc versus Batteries Calc?
I was working through converting a proof to calc style (see original here) and came across this strangeness:
--import Mathlib.Tactic

def pow256_shr (n : Nat) (m : UInt8) (k : Nat) (p : n < 256^k) : (m.val * 256^k + n < 256^(k+1)) := by
  have mLt : (m.val : Nat) < 256 := m.val.isLt
  calc
    _ < 256 * 256^k := by sorry
    _ = 256^(k+1) := by sorry

On Lean 4.7.0 the above succeeds (ignoring the sorry) for now.  However, if I uncomment the import Mathlib.Tactic line, then it fails.  Here, Mathlib is imported with this line in the lakefile.lean:
require mathlib from git "https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4"@"v4.7.0"

(I couldn't use the latest commit because that did not compile)
Thoughts?

I see using e.g. import Mathlib.Tactic.GCongr allows it to pass.  That is very confusing.

Unfortunately unless you post a minimal working example (i.e. without imports to your own local project), it may be hard to diagnose.

Also, you know about the https://leanprover.zulipchat.com zulip instance? Unfortunately Lean experts don't tend to hang out on StackOverflow, and you'll typically get much better help by posting in the zulip.

Oh, it is really a standalone example.  I removed the import for "lean playground" --- it wasn't doing anything.
.
